# equivalent of C struct in C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio, struct

Could someone help me with what the equivalent of this C code is in C#?

```
struct { int left, right; } stack[MAX];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public struct PickAName
{
     public int left;
     public int right;
}

private const int MAX = 666;
PickAName[] stack = new PickAName[MAX];
```

or:

```
Stack<PickAName> stack = new Stack<PickAName>();
```

Comment: There's no reason to cripple the C# code just because it started as C.  `Stack<PickAName>` should always be preferred.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I've almost no experience with C#, I just gave him the translation he asked for

Answer (score 3):

```
public struct PickAName
{
     public int left;
     public int right;
}
```

Not sure what stack[MAX] does.

If you want to use a "stack" in pseudocode terms, do:

```
Stack<PickAName> stack = new Stack<PickAName>();
stack.Push(new PickAName());
stack.Pop();
```

Comment: what stack[MAX] does is declare an array (MAX items long) of instances of the struct defined at the start of the line.

Comment: Well, I am translating a C algorithm for quick sorting to C#. And now I have to translate the iterative code and a structure is needed. I can post the full code if you want and explanations on it but I think the snippet you gave will do the job.